# Insert array in db mysql

Tags: php, database, arrays

I have an array in php  like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'idprodotto' => '1',
    'prodotto' => 'Banana',
    'cordinaten' => '42.75495',
    'cordinatee' => '13.9365',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'idprodotto' => '2',
    'prodotto' => 'Pera',
    'cordinaten' => '42.74159',
    'cordinatee' => '13.88792',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'idprodotto' => '3',
    'prodotto' => 'Mela',
    'cordinaten' => '42.65719',
    'cordinatee' => '13.89273',
  ),
)
```

How insert in db ? i have field idprodotto prodotto cordinaten cordinatee but how insert?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SafeMysql library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) for this.

Assuming you have a connection already established, all the code you need is

```
foreach ($array_with_data as $row)
    $db->query("INSERT INTO table SET ?u",$row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The native way is to set on a for-each-loop, then iterate through the array and iterate through it and execute a query that inserts a single-line into a table for each field in the array.